# lisp do loop factorial code

Tags: lisp

```
(defun fact (n)
    (do
       ((i 1 (+ 1 i))
        (prod 1 (* i prod)))
       ((equal i n) prod)))
```

I have done the code above and when i try, `fact(4)`, it give me `ans is 6`. I am not sure what is going wrong. Can anyone help me?

Comment: it return 24 ..any idea what's going wrong ??

Comment: Yup, I just gave the answer :D

Comment: I would try `(fact 4)` instead of `fact(4)`  - when programming in Lisp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
(defun fact (n)
    (do
       ((i 1 (+ 1 i))
        (prod 1 (* i prod)))
       ((equal i (+ n 1)) prod)))
```

Basically, you were doing one iteration less than necessary.

Comment: thanks .. but when i change it to 0, i try number 2-10 .. and the answer for all is 0 ...

Comment: when i compile, it is ok . but when i try to run the program -> fact(4) .. it gives me error as shown at below ..

Error: Attempt to take the value of the unbound variable `&'.
[condition type: UNBOUND-VARIABLE]

any idea ??

Comment: Damn the keyboard. It should have been a `1` there.

Answer (score 3):

Mihai has already given the answer.

I would write it as:

```
(defun fact (n)
  (do ((i    1 (+ 1 i))
       (prod 1 (* i prod)))
      ((> i n) prod)))
```

Common Lisp has all the usual arithmetic predicates which work for numbers: `=`, `<`, `>`, ...

Comment: ok .. thanks to the suggestion. i will notice that next time.